# 10 rows triangle pattern printing in C language : increment numbers and decrement alphabet

Tags: c

How will we print the below pattern in C language? Please explain the logic.

```
         1
        12A
       123BA
      1234CBA
     12345DCBA
    123456EDCBA
   1234567FEDCBA
  12345678GFEDCBA
 123456789HGFEDCBA
12345678910IHGFEDCBA
```

Comment: Hello and welsome to SE. This isn't "do-my-homework" site, please, follow [ask] instructions

Comment: @MichalPolovka this is my first post sir, I didn't know. Thanks, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain the logic.

To print `num_lines` of that pattern
for each `line` from `1` to including `num_lines` do:
print `num_lines - line` spaces
print each number `i` from `1` to including `line`
print each character from `'A' + line - 2` to including `'A'`
print a newline character
repeat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logical structure, but you have to finish yourself.

```
int d,i,j,z; //d number of lines

for(i=0;i<d;i++) 
{
    for(j=d-i;j>0;j--) //display spaces
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(z)  
    {
        printf("*"); //what u want to display, you can use a table for strings, etc                
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Declare/define variables as close as possible to where they're used. Don't use one-letter-identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int alphabet=65;   //storing ascii value of 'A'

for(int i=0;i<=10-1;i++){   //for loop to print rows
    for(int spaces=1;spaces<=11-i;spaces++){   //to print spaces
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for(int increase=1;increase<=i+1;increase++){  //loop to print increasing numbers
        System.out.print(increase);
    }

    //to print alphabets in decreasing order
    for(int decrease=i;decrease>0;decrease--){  
        // converting ascii value of int value to our required character
        char alpha=(char) ((char) alphabet + decrease-1);
        System.out.print(alpha);
    } 
    
    // when we come out of top loop we print newline character 
    // so our answers are printed in different rows each time loop is completed
    System.out.println();   
}
```

Comment: This code is in java.

Comment: Yes.  And you're answering an obvious homework question that someone asked three years ago.  So this answer probably isn't too helpful.

Comment: stackoverflow isnt about one person but if someone comes looking for it then i thought this might help. I have been trying for past an hour this question and finally, i figured out something so i thought it might help someone 6 years down the line :).